# How to get all entries with second highest value of a Hashmap?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to get the second max number or value of a Map by using Java Streams.

**If multiple values are present then also I want both key and value.**

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();       
    map.put("Pankaj",1);
    map.put("Amit",2);
    map.put("Rahul",5);
    map.put("Chetan",7);
    map.put("Vinod",6);
    map.put("Amit",8);
    map.put("Rajesh", 7);
        
Entry<String, Integer> m = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
    .skip(1)
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

Comment: Can you explain, what is not working with your code? And what is your question exactly?

Comment: Why is your map inserting same key twice i.e. `Amit` ?

Answer (score 3):

> If multiple values are present then also I want both key and value.

Your code works only for a single value. In order to get the multiple values, group the entries on their values and then apply your code on the `Stream` derived from the resulting `Map`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("Pankaj", 1);
        map.put("Amit", 2);
        map.put("Rahul", 5);
        map.put("Chetan", 7);
        map.put("Vinod", 6);
        map.put("Amit", 8);
        map.put("Rajesh", 7);

        List<Entry<String, Integer>> result = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                .skip(1)
                .findFirst()
                .get()
                .getValue();

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
[Rajesh=7, Chetan=7]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would collect the map into a TreeMap sorted by the keys in reverse order using `groupingBy`. Then get the 2nd element from it using *skip* as,

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> treeMap = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                    () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.<Integer>reverseOrder()),
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));

Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> result = treeMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .skip(1)
            .findFirst()
            .get();
System.out.println(result);
```

Outputs,

```
7=[Rajesh, Chetan]
```

Note, we are assuming a second-max will always be present as we call `get` on an `Optional`.

Answer (score 1):

**Be simple!** The key word is a **second max**. It means you should use `PriorityQueue`:

```java
Queue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> maxQueue = new PriorityQueue<>((one, two) ->
                              Integer.compare(two.getValue(), one.getValue()));
maxQueue.addAll(map.entrySet());

Map.Entry<String, Integer> firstMax = maxQueue.remove();
Map.Entry<String, Integer> secondMax = maxQueue.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient way to get all second highest elements without any sorting:

[*Online Demo*](https://ideone.com/4cSPqI)

```bash
static Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("Pankaj",1, "Amita",2,
    "Rahul",5, "Chetan",7, "Vinod",6, "Amit",8, "Rajesh",7, "Foo",8);
static Integer max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
static List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // find max value first
    Integer max = map.values()
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(v -> v)
            .max().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

    // if it is not max then set max2
    map.entrySet().forEach(el -> {
        if (el.getValue() != max && el.getValue() >= max2) {
            if (el.getValue() != max2) {
                values.clear();
                max2 = el.getValue();
            }
            values.add(el.getKey());
        }
    });

    System.out.println(max2 + "=" + values);
}
```

**Output:**

```
7=[Rajesh, Chetan]
```